# How do you keep square shape when using Multires Modifier?

Tags: sculpting, multiresolution

I'm using the multires modifier to sculpt a weapon. For the most part I like how it subdivides the object - except for two areas. I want these areas to keep more of the original form square form. How would I do that? I tried adding edge loops and it made the geometry go nuts.

Here's what the base mesh square look is:

[image]

Here's what happens with my current level of multi-res:

[image]

Here are my multi res settings:

[image]

While not necessarily related to this - I would also love to know why the advanced settings are grayed out (but I can change them). I don't notice any impact on the model when I do change them though.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured this out for anyone who runs into the same issue. Set [Edge Creases](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/modeling/meshes/editing/edges.html) by selecting the Edge and changing the value in the Transform properties:

[image]

My result when setting it to 1:
[image]

Comment: or you could bevel the edges that you want to keep sharp if this is what you want?